# Asynchronous process connection - Node.js child_process

Tags: node.js

To my knowledge, child_process creation is asynchronous in Node.js - how do we know if a child_process is ready to receive messages, eg IPC? Are we able to check for a "ready" event, or "created" event?

I see no such event listed here:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess

Is there something I missing here? Normally with async processes we need to wait for a callback or an event to fire before proceeding.

Comment: You could listen to `message` event and have your child process send a message when it's ready: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_message But I don't think it's necessary to wait, the IPC message will probably be queued until the child processes it.

Comment: I'm not an expert of the child_process, but the fork method seems to be a good approach for you : it create a link between the parent and child process (kind of IPC) : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options (and see in the Child process doc introduction as well). Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume the child is started and ready.  Node will buffer async messages you send (up to a limit).

As of Node v5.8.0 there is a callback you can register on the `send` to be invoked if there is an error (so you can be notified if the send fails).  Additionally, the [child_process.send doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) says:

> If no callback function is provided and the message cannot be sent, an
>   'error' event will be emitted by the ChildProcess object. This can
>   happen, for instance, when the child process has already exited.

Basically, because so much stuff can go wrong, you can't really know your child process is up and running correctly until your application actually talks to it and gets a valid response back that is meaningful to your code.  So any generic information from node about the "success" of forking off the child process would just be a hint about its readiness, so they don't bother providing such a weak signal.

If your child node process truly is async, and your parent process doesn't have any real communication to do with the child, then you'll need to add your own "I'm fine" message.  The parent can expect the child to send a message (`process.send({ startup: 'OK' })`).  Though this will quickly devolve into an on-going health-check if you want to know the child process is continuing to function correctly (which may be a bit more than you wanted, but is probably where you'll end up).